# finding my location doesn't work on xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, geolocation

While building my xamarin app I noticed a rather strange behaviour on xamarin.ios. I'm using the geolocator.plugin to find my location and than ofcourse I use this location as I need it through the app. Everything  works fine in xamarin.android project but in the xamarin.ios the stops as soon as I call the service on which I find the location. This is a sample of my code:

service.cs

```
    public async Task<Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position> GetDeviceCurrentLocation()
    {
        try
        {
            var locator = Plugin.Geolocator.CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            if (position != null)
            {
                return position;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to get location, may need to increase timeout: " + ex);
        }

        return new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position();
    }
```

and this is my MyViewExample.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MyViewExample : ContentPage
    {
        public MyViewExample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Service cs = new Service();
            var myLocation = Task.Run(() => api.GetDeviceCurrentLocation()).Result;
            var myLatitude = myLocation.Latitude;
            var myLongitude = myLocation.Longitude; 
            Debug.Writeline("Latitude is : " + myLatitude + " and Longitude is : " + myLongitude);
         }
     }
```

this is my info.plist file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
            --
            --
            --
            --
            --
            --
            <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
            <string>LaunchScreen</string>
            <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
            <string>This app needs access location when open and in the background</string>
            <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Need location for geolocator plugin</string>
            <key>RequestWhenInUseAuthorization</key>
            <string>Need location for geolocator plugin</string>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>my.app.development</string>
        </dict>
    </plist>
```

Can anyone give me any clue on why I'm having trouble on getting location on xamarin.ios? Am I forgetting something? I've gone through numerous examples but none worked for me. 
Any idea on how can I approach at this problem? Any help would be crucial and highly appreciated :). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to increase `DesiredAccuracy`? Maybe your iOS device is not accurate enough?

Comment: Actually no, I didn't try it. I will try it now. The xamarin.ios app always gets stuck at this line `var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));` . Have you experienced any trouoble while using this plugin? @ChrFin

Comment: I did not use it, I just guessed, as this *could* be the problem...

Comment: Are you using the iOS Simulator or a phyiscal device?

Comment: I'm using both actually. It didn't work in neither of them :/ . It doesn't even asks for location permissions when the app starts for the first time. Any idea?

Comment: @sme ?? Have you experienced any trouoble while using this plugin? Have you ever used it?

Comment: Yes, I am using this plugin and it works on my physical device, but not the simulator. Try adding this key to info.plist: `<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key><string>abc 123</string>`. I don't have the code in front of me right now so I can't remember exactly how I have it set up.

Comment: Also, make sure you have the options to receive background location updates enabled.

Comment: If your device's version is iOS 11, use `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription`. If you want to deploy on early version, add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationUsageDescription`.

Comment: Thanks @LandLu-MSFT already added these keys. Anyway I managed to solve it...so thanks anyway :)

Comment: @sme thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my task was async, I needed to `await` this task. But instead of await-ing it I used this line of code to run the task on the main thread.

`var myLocation = Task.Run(() => cs.GetDeviceCurrentLocation()).Result;`

And this was the problem with my app. Looks like xamarin.ios doesn't support this kind of "hack". As soon as I made an another method asynchronus and used this line

`var myLocation = await cs.GetDeviceCurrentLocation();`

everything worked like charm. Hope it helps others looking for an answer of the same problem :)